# How to temporarily disable a database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have several PHP databases for different websites on my shared hosting account. In most cases the database name helps me identify which database belongs to which site. However, there are some databases with nondescript names. I want to delete any database that’s not being used. Is there a way to temporarily disable an entire database on phpMyAdmin so I can test each site and make sure I won't be deleting a database I need to keep?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is the database client. MySQL is the database. It's important to not confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable a database, you can only disable access to it, and you can only do that if you have individual accounts for each database.

While you can't rename databases, you can rename all the tables within a database to see if anything breaks.